# Inference while controlling False Discovery rates given known dependence between test statistics

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate

I have a number $n$ of standard normal test statistics $\boldsymbol{\beta}$, each of which belonging to a hypothesis I want to test. So under H$_0$

$$\boldsymbol{\beta} \sim N(\mathbf{0}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma})$$

where $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ has been estimated using maximum likelihood theory. How can I test all $n$ hypotheses separately, while controlling the false discovery rate but maintaining maximal power by leveraging my knowledge of $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$?

I've been looking through the literature but can't quite seem to find what I want.

What I do *not* want is:

- A chi-squared omnibus test
- A very general correction on the p-values that is too conservative
- A procedure that assumes $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ unknown
- A procedure based on dependence in the *data*

Comment: Are you conflating conducting a group of pairwise tests of the same kind with control of the FDR? The former provides *p*-values – **including for dependent data** (e.g., paired *t* test) – for each pairwise test, while the latter is a procedure for controlling false positives due to having more than a single test, regardless of whether the specific tests were dependent or not.

Comment: The Benjamini-Hochberg FDR adjustment method only cares if the tests themselves have negatively dependent rejection probabilities; [a condition which is difficult to imagine even hypothtically](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111756/the-meaning-of-positive-dependency-as-a-condition-to-use-the-usual-method-for). (Especially note amoeba's answer, and ignore Chris C's which is more or less irrelevant and contains misinformation).

Comment: @Alexis No I am not conflating both, I really want FDR control for correlated tests. I know Benjamini-Hochberg or if necessary Benjamini-Yekutieli will work, but I am concerned about power. My feeling is that there must be something more powerful given that you know the full covariance structure.