# Question about power of FDR and FWE

Tags: multiple-comparisons, statistical-power, false-discovery-rate, type-i-and-ii-errors, familywise-error

I understand that false discovery rate (FDR) is $\leq$ familywise error rate (FWE).  I have read this means that controlling FDR is hence "more powerful" than controlling FWE.  What does more powerful mean in this multiple testing context?

Comment: It means you can allow a looser threshold to declare significance with FDR-controlling procedures, thereby rejecting more hypotheses, thereby having higher power.

Comment: @BigBendRegion Thanks for the comment. I have since thought about this. But from what I gather, I don't see how the looser threshold implies an FDR controlling procedure necessarily rejects more hypotheses than an FWE controlling procedure. I asked about this here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/555877/does-a-procedure-controlling-fdr-at-level-alpha-always-reject-at-least-as-muc

Comment: Eg, p< .03 happens more often than p< .01.